# Formula for the graph of 3 hyperbolas

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I recently was doing some complex number work and found this guy:
[image: Hyperbola with three curves]

Is there a formula for a graph like this in two - dimensions? I know that the values are the same on every curve, but they are rotated (in polar coordinates) by $ 2 \pi / 3 $. A similar graph with the case $ n = 2 $ is a perfect hyperbola and I have a formula, but this would be the case where $ n = 3 $.

Note that the center of the formulas are the roots of the cyclotomic polynomials (This is a graph in the complex plane).

Comment: Could it be $r=\sec(3\theta)$?

Comment: @f'' Hey, I think you are right! Want to put in some kind of answer? Or should I answer myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural way to get this using complex numbers is to look at $z^3$ where $z = x + i y.$ Then take a level set of, say, the real part, so set
$$ x^3 - 3 x y^2 = 1  $$
This is not quite the same as the comments, this is
$$ r^3 = \sec 3 \theta $$

[image]

Comment: Yup! That's what it is. I clearly have a lot to learn about the complex numbers!

Comment: This wouldn't be the same graph as $ r = \sec(3\theta) $ right?

Comment: @theREALyumdub almost, it is $r^3 = \sec 3 \theta.$